# Programmatically Polling Google Maps Quota Usage

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there any way to programmatically poll the maps API for quota usage?

i.e. I would like to know when I'm approaching the daily limit without having to manually view it in a console. I would love to have a script run once an hour and alert me if I'm using X% of the quota.

Thanks!

Comment: Somebody created a similar feature request in the public issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=11293. You can star it to express your interest and receive updates.

Comment: Thanks!
That's actually my feature request :)

Comment: I added my two cents to your feature request. They are keeping track of it so they should be able to return a current count with each response to a api request. That would be extremely beneficial for keeping track of quota and knowing when to fall back appropriately.