# How can my code detect when Google map 25,000 api load limit is reached?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Google allows a domain to load the google map API 25,000 times per day for free.  Once that limit is hit then your map stops working for the rest of that day unless you buy more API loads.

How can my javascript detect when that limit is reached so I can fail as gracefully as possible by displaying an informative message?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_exceed

Comment: The same question was asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41659261/programmatically-polling-google-maps-quota-usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news from Google.  Looks like they posted a solution last month.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages

I search SO on OverQuotaMapError but got no hits

Here is the post I made today on SO seeking advice for how to catch this 'error' with code.
[How to catch OverQuotaMapError for a Google map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45201174/how-to-catch-overquotamaperror-for-a-google-map)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at  the [API Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference) for Javascript.

Let's say you're making a GeoCoder Request, of the form `Geocoder().geocode(request:GeocoderRequest, callback:function(Array<GeocoderResult>, GeocoderStatus))`

That second parameter in the callback is going to give some useful information about the response, including if it is over the rate limit.

To check if you are over the limit, compare the status code to the constant

```
google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT
```

and handle the error accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Andrew but I think I am asking a different question.  Google's documentation for their maps API does not have any info showing how to detect when the 25,000/day API load limit is reached.  If there is a way to trigger a callback routine, I have not found it yet.

Comment: Which API are referring to? This one? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

Comment: Yes, I am referring to the google map javascript API which I am loading from https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js.  I seem to recall seeing a solution a couple of years ago but cannot find it.

Comment: I've seen a couple of similar questions floating around on StackOverflow (including this one from 5 years ago.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665696/how-to-detect-that-the-25000-request-per-day-limit-has-been-reached-in-google-ma) and it seems like it's still only possible to check the API Usage through the process described here: https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/7036164, and not programmatically...

Comment: I think Andrew is correct with the above. Monitoring via the API Console seems to be the way to go, afaik.

Comment: Yeah, so far I am hitting that same deadend.  If this is currently not doable in javascript then I will post an enhancement request in google's bug tracker.

Comment: Monitoring the API console will tell **me** why my map stopped working but it sure leaves my users with an awful experience.  Worse yet, most will blame me for building a crummy map that does not work.  Might be time to look at Leaflet.

Comment: It would be nice to hear something definitive from Google in this point. (hint hint)

Comment: Here is my feature request to Google.  
  
[https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=11460](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=11460)  
  
If this feature would help you, please give it a star.

Comment: @Gmap4guy Subscribed!

Comment: For anyone who comes upon this thread, the enhancement request I posted on Google's issue tracker has been merged into: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=11293