# How to catch OverQuotaMapError for a Google map?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

If my javascript code attempts to load the Google map API more then 25,000 times in a day then Google will write OverQuotaMapError to the window.console.
See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages

Is OverQuotaMapError a property or a value in the window.console object?
What is the recommended code to see if this ‘error’ has occurred?

I have a wildland fire map that will likely hit the API load limit later today.  When that happens I want to be display an informative message to my users.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me.  If you open the google documentation link I posted and scroll to the bottom then you will see a link to advice from Google for how to check for any of these errors via your code.